# What is the best way to remove particular strings in data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

Can any one help me with best way to remove the below string in data programatically? Thanks in advance.

My TextFile:

```
-------------------------------------------- 

-       All Data Monthly        - 

-------------------------------------------- 

Local date-time is [2017-10-03 04:05:18.531] 

-------------------------------------------- 

C NUMBER                   |SR LOCATION     |COUNTY                                                                                
1234                       |SFO             |IND
```

I want to remove the below string in data using python program.The string format remains same but the values changes

```
 -------------------------------------------- 

-       All Data Monthly        - 

-------------------------------------------- 

Local date-time is [2017-10-03 04:05:18.531] 

--------------------------------------------
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Does this only occur once in your file? Is it the only time you ever see a series of `-------` characters?

Comment: @birryree I will be getting these every time i download data from main site through HTTP

Comment: So every time you download it, you will get this file with this header occurring once? If so, you could trim the text down each time - easiest way would be to break the string into a list of lines, and then iterate through until you get through the third line of `-----...`

Comment: @birryree Thanks i will try to loop and trim them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# a simple approach that assumes the unwanted header occurs once at
# the top of the file.
with open('s.py') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i < 10: continue
        print line.rstrip() # or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the index of the part  in the string that you want to trim, for example :

```
str1 = "this is string example....wow!!!"
str2 = "exam"
print str1.find(str2)
```

That will give you 15 which is the index of "exam" in this string

If python can't find the string inside the original string it will return -1 so adopt your code accordingly with if statement

Now you just need to get a substring of the original string by doing something like that.

```
subString = str1[:15]
```

That will assign subString to the new value of "hello "

You can do the same by finding any index in your string and trim any part of the string

```
original_string[start-index:end-index]
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime as dt

lines=[]

#Open testfile.txt and append all the content into a list
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        #To remove the '\n' at the end of every line
        lines.append(line.replace('\n', '')
#slicing the list containing the contents of 'testfile.txt' so that only the required stuff remains.
lines=lines[:9]
#I just added this to change the "local date-time is..." line and put the current date-time.
lines[6]=("Local date-time is [{}]".format(dt.datetime.now()))

#Finally, write all of the content into testfile.txt
with open("testfile.txt", "w") as file:
    for line in lines:
        file.write(str(line)+'\n')
```

I hope the comment lines are enough to explain what the code does. If not, please comment down and I'll try to explain.